# Как отслеживать нажатие клавиш в python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-keyboard

я пишу программу которая должна отслеживать нажатие клавиш но в ней отображается нажатие и отжатие клавиш но мне нужно только нажатия может кто не будь  помочь, вот мой код:

```
import keyboard
def print_pressed_keys(e):
    print(e.name)
keyboard.hook(print_pressed_keys)
keyboard.wait()
```

и его полная версия взятая с этого же сайта:

```
import keyboard

translate = {
    'down':' нажал на клавишу ',
    'up':' отпустил клавишу '
}


def print_pressed_keys(e):
    print(
        'Пользователь {}{}'.format(translate[e.event_type], e.name)
        )


keyboard.hook(print_pressed_keys)
keyboard.wait()
```

Comment: Поставьте условие `if e.event_type == "down":`, это и будет проверкой, что это событие нажатия.

Answer (score 0):

Просто нужно добавить проверку на нажатие, таким образом выкинуть отжатие.

```
import keyboard
def print_pressed_keys(e):
    if e.event_type == 'down':
        print(e.name)
keyboard.hook(print_pressed_keys)
keyboard.wait()
```

Answer (score 0):

У меня была такая проблема, я решил её так:

```
recorded = keyboard.record(until='esc')
recorded = recorded[::2]#Я сохраняю только каждое второе значение
```

вывод:

Был - <KeyboardEvent (d down)>, <KeyboardEvent (d up)>

Стал - <KeyboardEvent (d up)>

Надеюсь помог.